# Adding mean lines to catagorical jitter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a jitter plot with a y axis of frequencies and an x axis of categories. Within each category there is two groups:

```
ggplot(plot_core_FGT_free, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = origin))+
  geom_jitter()+
  labs(y = "Frequency", x = "Metadata factors")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Gene duplication", "BGC proximity", "Horizontal gene transfer", "Known target"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank() ,
        text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1))+
  scale_color_grey(start = 0.3, end = 0.7)
```

[image]

I want to add these means to each respective category and group:

```
     mean                 origin marker         
[1,] "0.3715"             "free" "Gene duplication"  
[2,] "0.15175"            "free" "BGC proximity"
[3,] "0.54125"            "free" "Horizontal gene transfer"    
[4,] "0.10525"            "free" "Known target" 
[5,] "0.344423076923077"  "FGT"  "Gene duplication"  
[6,] "0.146153846153846"  "FGT"  "BGC proximity"
[7,] "0.425576923076923"  "FGT"  "Horizontal gene transfer"    
[8,] "0.0790384615384615" "FGT"  "Known target"
```

I have tried using `geom_segment` and various `stat_summary`methods to no avail, can anyone help me?

EDIT:

```
ggplot(plot_core_FGT_free, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = origin))+
  geom_boxplot(size = 1)+
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(), size = 2, alpha = 0.4) +
  labs(y = "Frequency", x = "Metadata factors")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) stringr::str_replace(x, " ", "\n")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Gene duplication", "BGC proximity", "Horizontal gene transfer", "Known target"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Those means are the actual means of your data? Coz you could handle it with an underlying boxplot

Comment: Yeh they are the means of the actual data :)

Comment: watch out: you're using two time `scale_x_discrete`! The second one will delete the first one! Why do you need the second one at all?

Comment: ah yeh forgot to remove the one you put in to split the label, The actual labels in my dataframe are not the ones i want on the plot, there are more machine friendly ones like `known_target` instead of `known target` for example

Comment: Then use: `scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) stringr::str_to_title(stringr::str_replace_all(x, "_", "\n")))`

Comment: Some are also short hand versions of the labels so I need to change the actual dataframe which i will do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it looks pretty good with a boxplot behind.

But personally I found really difficult to understand the differences between the colours you chose...

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# recreate a mock of your data
df1 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.3715 ), origin = "free", variable = "Gene duplication")
df2 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.15175), origin = "free", variable = "BGC proximity")
df3 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.54125), origin = "free", variable = "Horizontal gene transfer")
df4 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.10525), origin = "free", variable = "Known target")
df5 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.344423076923077 ), origin = "FGT" , variable = "Gene duplication")
df6 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.146153846153846 ), origin = "FGT" , variable = "BGC proximity")
df7 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.425576923076923 ), origin = "FGT" , variable = "Horizontal gene transfer")
df8 <- tibble(value = rnorm(100, 0.0790384615384615), origin = "FGT" , variable = "Known target")
df <- bind_rows(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8)
```

Your Chart + boxplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = origin))+
  geom_boxplot(size = 1)+
  geom_jitter()+
  labs(y = "Frequency", x = "Metadata factors") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank() ,
        text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_color_grey(start = 0.3, end = 0.7)
```

[image]

If I may, I would suggest you this option instead:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = origin))+
  geom_boxplot(size = 1)+
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(), size = 2, alpha = 0.4) +
  labs(y = "Frequency", x = "Metadata factors")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) stringr::str_replace(x, " ", "\n")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this aesthetic, thank you! Yeh the colours sucked but were picked by my PI. When using you suggested plot I am seeing no box plot for the `known target`variable, strange.

Comment: LoL I figured there was a reason behind that.. Looked like colours for a paper.. Btw if you think it's the right answer you should select it so that other users may know.. If you need other edits let me know.

Comment: You see no boxplot but you should see at least a unique line. That's coz the data are really close to each other. If not so, post a picture of it..

Comment: I really don't like the dull colours papers make us use!! I have added an edit of the figure i am getting so you can see what I mean by no box plot for `known target` its mass is heavily towards zero but I should still see the tails ?

Comment: You dont see the long tail coz the ones on the top are heavy outliers. So they should be represented with small dots. Do you see some dots that are smaller than others? Those smaller dots are drawn by the `geom_boxplot`, while the bigger ones by the `geom_point`. If you dont want it this way but you prefer to have long tails till the very last point, it can be done.

Comment: Ahh yes I see them, hmm I am not sure what is better, my only worry it people might confuse the small dots for actual data points. How would I make it so the tail goes the whole way?

Comment: You can remove the small dots with this `geom_boxplot(size = 1, outlier.shape = NA) `. I'll check how to make the tail go all the way now

Answer (score 1):

The following will plot the mean lines. The trick is to pass a new `data` argument to `geom_segment`. Variable `segm_len` is the segments' length. The code was simplified to focus on the question problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

segm_len <- 0.8

ggplot(df, aes(variable, value, color = origin)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_segment(data = dfmean %>% mutate(marker = as.integer(factor(marker))),
               aes(x = marker - segm_len/2, xend = marker + segm_len/2, 
                   y = mean, yend = mean, 
                   color = origin)) +
  scale_color_grey(start = 0.3, end = 0.7) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1))
```

**Data**

```
dfmean <- read.table(text = '
     mean                 origin marker         
"0.3715"             "free" "Gene duplication"  
"0.15175"            "free" "BGC proximity"
"0.54125"            "free" "Horizontal gene transfer"    
"0.10525"            "free" "Known target" 
"0.344423076923077"  "FGT"  "Gene duplication"  
"0.146153846153846"  "FGT"  "BGC proximity"
"0.425576923076923"  "FGT"  "Horizontal gene transfer"    
"0.0790384615384615" "FGT"  "Known target"
', header = TRUE)

dfmean[[1]] <- as.numeric(as.character(dfmean[[1]]))
```